# aws get an embedded dashboard url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I'm trying to use the cli to retrieve an embedded quicksight dashboard url. 
However, I keep getting the error `QuickSightUserNotFoundException`.

I was following this guide to retrieve the url [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_GetDashboardEmbedUrl.html).

The steps:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn "<ARN>" --role-session-name testsession
```

which returns

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "<KEY>",
        "SecretAccessKey": "<KEY>",
        "SessionToken": "<TOKEN>",
        "Expiration": "2019-07-04T04:54:21Z"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "<ID>:testsession",
        "Arn": "<ARN>/testsession"
    }
}
```

Then I execute

```
aws quicksight get-dashboard-embed-url --aws-account-id <ID> --dashboard-id <ID> --identity-type IAM
```

which returns the error

```
An error occurred (QuickSightUserNotFoundException) when calling the GetDashboardEmbedUrl operation: Could not find user information in QuickSight
```

Assuming now that the user is not part of QuickSight, I execute the command below to add the user

```
aws quicksight register-user --aws-account-id <ID> --namespace default --identity-type IAM --iam-arn "<ARN>" --user-role READER --session-name "testsession" --email user123@example.com --region us-east-1
```

which returns

```
{
    "Status": 201,
    "User": {
        "Arn": "<ARN>/testsession",
        "UserName": "<NAME>/testsession",
        "Email": "user123@example.com",
        "Role": "READER",
        "Active": false,
        "PrincipalId": "<ID>"
    },
    "RequestId": "<ID>"
}
```

Now trying the get url from before again I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a Policy for the QuickSight user and attach it to the same?
You can check which user is allowed on QuickSight by running the following command:

```
aws quicksight list-users --aws-account-id <account-id> --namespace default --region <region-name>
```

This will list all the users who are allowed to use and access your QuickSight instance.

Also, check this latest blog about embedding the QuickSight Analytics:

```
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-multi-tenant-analytics-in-applications-with-amazon-quicksight/
```